# Retrieve value of top element in xml file with VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am trying to get the value of the element `totalHits` in the XML example below but in vain. I get the other elements in the rest of the XML file but struggle to get the one at the top of the file.

XML file:

```xml
<result xmlns="urn:com:tradedoubler:pf:model:xml:output" xmlns:ns2="urn:com:tradedoubler:pf:model:xml:common" version="3.0">
<productHeader>
<totalHits>4907</totalHits>
</productHeader>
<products>
```

I tried using:

```
doc.SelectSingleNode("result/productHeader/totalHits").innerText
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That is not proper XML.  Where does Products start at?  You can see ProductHeader, but no Product starting node.

Comment: `dim value = doc["result"]["productHeader"].InnerText` or `dim value = doc.GetElementsByTagName("totalHits").OfType<XmlElement>().FirstOrDefault().InnerText`. Many other ways.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, your XML sample is not well-formed. I had to fix it. The rest is trivial by using *LINQ to XML*.

> VB.NET

```vb
Sub Main
    Dim myXml As XElement = <result xmlns="urn:com:tradedoubler:pf:model:xml:output"
        xmlns:ns2="urn:com:tradedoubler:pf:model:xml:common" version="3.0">
    <productHeader>
        <totalHits>4907</totalHits>
    </productHeader>
</result>

    Dim ns1 As XNamespace = "urn:com:tradedoubler:pf:model:xml:output"
    Console.WriteLine(myXml.Descendants(ns1 + "productHeader").Elements(ns1 + "totalHits").Value)
End Sub
```

> Output

```
+------+
| 4907 |
+------+
```

Comment: Thnaks guys. I agree the xml format is not correct but I dont have any control over it